# Python , just opening a .csv file from desktop on mac os

Tags: python, file, csv

I just want to open a .csv file . I have it on my desktop and I looked up the file path in the file info.

```
 with open('Untitled:/Users/stephan/Desktop/cities.csv', "r") as f:
```

I get this error:

> No such file or directory

.

I know this is super stupid to ask, but it just does not work:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the right path to the desktop, try this :

```
import os   
userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
csvfile= userhome + r'\Desktop\cities.csv'
with open(csvfile, "r") as f:
```

Comment: That did not work (at least for me), you need to change the \ with /

Answer (score 3):

try specifying like this:

```
open('/Users/stephan/Desktop/cities.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. This is like @Uri Goren did but with the \ changed with /

```
import csv
import os

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
csvfile = userhome + r'/Desktop/DFKP_Fields.csv'
with open(csvfile, 'r') as data:
    for line in csv.DictReader(data):
        print(line)
```